# Mysql limit top 1 row by group

Tags: mysql

I am trying to extract the top 1 row of each group. I am very new to mysql and not too sure on how to limit

Table clientcontracts

```
Client  Products    contract_date
A       pepsi       13/02/16
A       Cola        11/01/16
A       fanta       22/03/16
B       pepsi       15/01/16
B       Cola        18/01/16
B       fanta       12/03/16
c       pepsi       15/03/16
c       Cola        18/03/16
c       fanta       10/02/16
```

I have done,

```
select Client,Products,contract_date 
from clientcontracts
group by Client,Products,contract_date
order by client,contract_date asc
limit 1
```

I have provided the actual and expected output below. Many thanks

```
>     Actual output:
>     A Cola    11/01/16
>      
>     What i want:
>      
>      A    Cola    11/01/16
>      B    pepsi   15/01/16 
>      C    fanta   10/02/16
```

Comment: What are the columns field name in the table?

Comment: What is the type of `contract_date` ? Is it a proper MySQL type ?

Comment: Hi @Lachie, the type of contract_date is timestamp

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to group by client with minimum date?

```
SELECT Client, Products, contract_date 
FROM clientcontracts 
GROUP by Client 
ORDER BY Client, contract_date ASC
```

Comment: I am trying to find the earliest contract date and the product used by the client.

Comment: Hi @sef4eg : It is simpler than i thought.. I could actually group by client and it works. Thank you :)

Comment: @ChristopherRajendran that's exactly what I did ;) You are very welcome

Comment: I'm not quite sure it will exactly return what you want. The `group by` will do the job to only output one row per client, but are you sure it is the right product that will associated with the right time ? It seems to me that the `group by` will have an unpredictable effect on the value returned for `products`

Answer (score 0):

give that a chance. it select all rows, order it, number it from 1 to n each group and shows only rows with nr = 1.

```
    SELECT @nr:= IF( @lastval = (@lastval:=concat(`Client`,'-',contract_date)) , @mnr:=@nr+1, 1) AS nr
    ,  m.* 
    FROM (
      SELECT CLIENT, Products, contract_date 
      FROM clientcontracts 
      ORDER BY `Client`, contract_date ASC
      ) AS m
     CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @nr:=0 , @lastval:='' ) AS parameter
     WHERE nr = 1;
```